# wifi driver for Samsung Tab Pro S Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, samsung, 17.04

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my samsung tab pro S but the wifi does not work. I want to know if there is a driver I can install using a usb. 
for Samsung Tab pro S the wifi is " Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac MIMO ". I really don't know that much about Linux just very basic things so if anyone can help get my wifi working for Samsung Tab Pro S I would be very thankful to the community.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn` to your question

Comment: Android Dev I'm not really too sure what you mean by add the output lspci -knn to my question? do you mean the tags that I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [github](https://github.com/infernix/samsung_tabpro_s) page dedicated to this machine.

You need at least kernel 4.5 (Ubuntu 17.04 uses 4.10) and it has issues with wifi, brightness (both fixed) and audio (no fix). Regarding the wifi:

> The NIC is an ath10k QCA6174. The firmware support for this device is rather messy and the wrong set of files will break it. Place the contents of the ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0 dir in /lib/firmware and be sure to delete anything else in there. This firmware works very well (30MByte/s on 5ghz without issue) on 4.7.x.

Comment: I have went to the solution you provided and I followed all the instruction from github. not working but i'll keep trying.

Comment: I got the wifi working thank you, btw do you know where i should paste the brightness folder because i not too sure where i should place the foler

Comment: On the page it says: "It should be started with your display manager or in your user session." So anywhere you want, make it executable and then add it to startup applications.

Comment: I found another way to change the brightness. 
To change the birghtness open up terminal type xrandr
get the display name and then type
xrandr --output "display name" --brightness (value from 0 {black screen} to 22+ {very white})